# Higher order radicals (nested roots)

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following functions

```
u2 = 2^(2/3) (12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2 + 12 g3^2 - 4 p^2 + 6 p (κ1 + κ2) - 3 (κ1^2 + κ1 κ2 + κ2^2))/.{g3 -> g1/g2*κ2/2};
u1 = 36 g1^2 (2 p - 3 κ2) - 36 g2^2 (4 p - 3 (κ1 + κ2)) + (2 p - 3 κ1) (36 g3^2 - (2 p - 3 κ2) (4 p - 3 (κ1 + κ2)));
```

I wish to solve for

```
g2/.(Solve[u1^2 + u2^3 == 0,g2]/.{Γ -> 20, κ1 -> 1, κ2 -> 2})
```

and I was returned with several solutions. However, all of the solutions have `Root` and `#`. Suggesting that they are of higher ordered radicals. I need to inspect the expressions fully. How should I go about removing the `Root` and `#`?

Comment: Why do you need to convert Root objects to radicals? Is there some code you have that doesn't work with Root objects, so you need radicals? Or, do you just feel more comfortable with radicals?

Comment: @CarlWoll I am trying to investigate `u1^2+u2^3 = 0` as a function of `g1` and `g2`. Now I'm trying to simplify the expression by giving `\[CapitalGamma]`, `\[Kappa]1` and `\[Kappa]2` so that I can see the `g1` and `g2` dependence clearer. You can remove `{Γ -> 20, κ1 -> 1, κ2 -> 2}` and you will still see `Root`

Point is, I'm more comfortable viewing the expression as a whole. Even when it's ugly.

Comment: My recommendation is to try to get comfortable working with Root objects, as they are simpler and more robust.

Comment: @CarlWoll I doubt that since the expressions are physics related and I will need to examine the expressions in detail to figure out what's going on. But thanks for your help.

Comment: The equation is a $6$th degree polynomial in $\sqrt{g2}$ equal to $0$. Only rarely are $6$th degree polynomial roots expressible in radicals.